# Transform a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm not a native English speaker.

For example, there is a sentence:

> "They made an example out of me".

How can I say it the other way, like:

> "I was made an example out of"?

Do these sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: First, lose the _out_; the idiom _make an example of_ doesn't require it. Second, go right ahead and say _I was made an example of_; it's one passive transform of _They made an example of me_. Another is _An example was made of me_. They have different syntax, but the same meanings; the only difference is which constituent gets fronted to become the topic.

Answer (score 1):

the idiom:  make an example (out) of (one) [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/example)

> To punish one harshly so that others will avoid committing the same
>   offense in order to avoid such punishment.

Your sentences:

> "They made an example out of me".

and

> "I was made an example of."

have the same meaning.  I edited out 'out' in the 2nd sentence.

Comment: They effectively have the same meaning, although, in the passive, it's not clear if *they* were the ones who made an example out of you. It could have been somebody else. But I'm not sure if that subtlety warrants excluding the second version. (It would depend on what, exactly, was trying to be said.)

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts "Out of which I was made an example" would work, but it would depend upon the particular sentence.

In this instance it would read very awkwardly.

Comment: Yeah, my question was whether both of my sentences have the same meaning?